# Google Play Console: Advertising ID error while submitting the app

Tags: android, flutter, google-analytics, google-play, google-play-console

I'm trying to submit a new version to Play Console, which targets API level 33 and has analytics integration. I was asked to submit the advertising ID declaration where I specified that I use Google Analytics in my app. Now, when uploading the file, I get the following message.

```
Your declaration on Play Console says that your app uses advertising ID. Your manifest file doesn't include the com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID permission.

If you don't include this permission in your manifest file, your advertising identifier will be zeroed out. This may break your advertising and analytics use cases, and cause loss of revenue.
```

Note that the `<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>` permission is set on my manifest file. Who faced this kind of issue? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: same here. Got any solution ??

Comment: no solution yet(

Comment: Did you figure it out @Laura

Answer (score 1):

Use google_mobile_ads >1.2.0. If target android 33 need use google
play service > 20.6.0 or if use google play service < 20.6.0 you need config AD ID in manifest

Comment: As I mentioned, my app targets API level 33 but doesn't use Ads in the app. Please read the question again

Comment: @Laura, `@Couldwe Doit` wants to know: "if have you been able to solve this, I find it funny I have to check yes in google playstore as if I'm using that in the manifest when I'm not even using that at all in the manifest"

Comment: @Couldwe Doit To ask specific users, you can tag them in comments like so.

Answer (score -1):

In the recent update if you are using analytics you have to select yes for the advertising declaration. To do this you have to use the toggle under, "Does your App use Advertising ID?"

[Check this](https://jtuto.com/solved-you-cant-submit-updates-as-some-information-about-your-app-is-incomplete-google-play/), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABByV.png)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32832451)